# Laravel 4 View being cached and will not update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am returning a view like so:

```
public function leaderboard()
{
    return ['view' => View::make('phones.leaderboard-table', ['data' => $this->leaderboardData()])->render(), 'counts' => $this->counts()];
}
```

The data for the leaderboard:

```
public function leaderboardData()
{
    $date = Input::get('date') ? \Carbon\Carbon::parse(Input::get('date')) : \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $leaderboard_data = [];

    $query = DB::table('phones_calls AS PC')
        ->select('U.id',
            DB::raw('CONCAT(UD.firstName, " fff", UD.lastName) AS trader_name'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS total_calls'),
            DB::raw('SUM(talkTime) AS talk_time'),
            DB::raw('AVG(talkTime) AS talk_time_avg'),
            DB::raw('MAX(date) AS last_call')
        )
        ->join('users AS U', 'U.id', '=', 'PC.userId')
        ->leftJoin('users_details AS UD', 'UD.userId', '=', 'U.id')
        ->leftJoin('company_zones AS CZ', 'CZ.id', '=', 'U.zone_id');
    if (Input::get('period') == 'week') {
        $query->where(DB::raw('DATE(PC.date)'), '>=', $date->startOfWeek());
    } elseif (Input::get('period') == 'month') {
        $query->where(DB::raw('DATE(PC.date)'), '>=', $date->startOfMonth());
    } elseif (Input::get('period') == 'year') {
        $query->where(DB::raw('DATE(PC.date)'), '>=', $date->startOfYear());
    } else {
        $query->where(DB::raw('DATE(PC.date)'), $date->toDateString());
    }

    $query->where('didConnect', 1)
        ->where('departmentId', 5)
        ->where('U.enabled', 1);
    if (Input::get('zone')) {
        $zone_ranges = explode(',', Input::get('zone'));
        $left = $zone_ranges[0];
        $right = $zone_ranges[1];
        $query->where('CZ.l', '>=', $left)
            ->where('CZ.r', '<=', $right);
    } else {
        $zone_ranges = explode(',', Auth::zone()->lr);
        $left = $zone_ranges[0];
        $right = $zone_ranges[1];
        $query->where('CZ.l', '>=', $left)
            ->where('CZ.r', '<=', $right);
    }
    $query->orderBy(DB::raw('SUM(talkTime)'), 'desc')
        ->groupBy('U.id');

    $q2 = clone $query;
    $q3 = clone $query;

    $outbound_data = $query->where('callTypeId', 2)->get();
    $inbound_data = $q2->where('callTypeId', 3)->get();
    $internal_data = $q3->where('callTypeId', 1)->get();

    foreach ($outbound_data as $data) {
        $leaderboard_data[$data->id]['trader_name'] = $data->trader_name;
        $leaderboard_data[$data->id]['outbound'] = $data;
    }

    foreach ($inbound_data as $data) {
        $leaderboard_data[$data->id]['trader_name'] = $data->trader_name;
        $leaderboard_data[$data->id]['inbound'] = $data;
    }

    foreach ($internal_data as $data) {
        $leaderboard_data[$data->id]['trader_name'] = $data->trader_name;
        $leaderboard_data[$data->id]['internal'] = $data;
    }
    return $leaderboard_data;
}
```

The view 'phones.leaderboard-table':

```
@foreach($data as $id => $row)
    <tr data-user-id="{{$id}}" class="{{($i == 1 ? "row-success" : "")}}{{Auth::id() == $id ? ' row-me' : ''}}">
        <td>{{$i++}}</td>
        <td>{{$row['trader_name']}}</td>

        <td>{{(isset($row['internal']) ? ($drilldown ? "<a href='#' class='drilldown' data-call-type-id='1'>" : "").number_format($row['internal']->total_calls).($drilldown ? "</a>" : "") : "-")}}</td>
        <td>{{(isset($row['internal']) ? formatSeconds($row['internal']->talk_time) : "-")}}</td>
        <td>{{(isset($row['internal']) ? formatSeconds($row['internal']->talk_time_avg) : "-")}}</td>
        <td>{{(isset($row['internal']) ? \Carbon\Carbon::parse($row['internal']->last_call)->diffForHumans() : "-")}}</td>

        <td>{{(isset($row['inbound']) ? ($drilldown ? "<a href='#' class='drilldown' data-call-type-id='3'>" : "").number_format($row['inbound']->total_calls).($drilldown ? "</a>" : "") : "-")}}</td>
        <td>{{(isset($row['inbound']) ? formatSeconds($row['inbound']->talk_time) : "-")}}</td>
        <td>{{(isset($row['inbound']) ? formatSeconds($row['inbound']->talk_time_avg) : "-")}}</td>
        <td>{{(isset($row['inbound']) ? \Carbon\Carbon::parse($row['inbound']->last_call)->diffForHumans() : "-")}}</td>

        <td>{{(isset($row['outbound']) ? ($drilldown ? "<a href='#' class='drilldown' data-call-type-id='2'>" : "").number_format($row['outbound']->total_calls).($drilldown ? "</a>" : "") : "-")}}</td>
        <td>{{(isset($row['outbound']) ? formatSeconds($row['outbound']->talk_time) : "-")}}</td>
        <td>{{(isset($row['outbound']) ? formatSeconds($row['outbound']->talk_time_avg) : "-")}}</td>
        <td>{{(isset($row['outbound']) ? \Carbon\Carbon::parse($row['outbound']->last_call)->diffForHumans() : "-")}}</td>

        <td>{{($drilldown ? "<a href='#' class='drilldown' data-call-type-id='0'>" : "").number_format(((isset($row['inbound']) ? $row['inbound']->total_calls : 0)+(isset($row['outbound']) ? $row['outbound']->total_calls : 0))).($drilldown ? "</a>" : "")}}</td>
        <td>{{formatSeconds((isset($row['inbound']) ? $row['inbound']->talk_time : 0)+(isset($row['outbound']) ? $row['outbound']->talk_time : 0))}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The problem is, is that it doesn't update no matter how I change the SQL etc.

How I disable view caching for this page? Or is there a better way to get this view in with the counts?

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem with the view. Views do get cached, but there is still php code in them making sure that different data is always rendered correctly.

Comment: @Jerodev The data coming back is correct but the view is definitely not updating.

Comment: So, you make changes to the view, but the web page remains the same?

Comment: It turns out that this was an issue with DataTables remembering the table state. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:
`php artisan cache:clear`

If that does not work, backup your app directory, then try manually removing all contents of these directories:

`app/storage/views/`

`app/storage/cache/`

Note: do not delete the directories themselves since Laravel will complain, just remove all files therein.

Comment: Tried all that before, no success :(